# Add custom attribute to product's HTML to woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to add a `data-attribute` to WooCommerce's cart page.

The cart page populates a table with each row being a product that has been added to the cart.

I'm able to add a data attribute into the HTML for this row like so:

**/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php**

```
<?php
  // For each item in cart
  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    // Get product
    $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    // Get custom attribute
    $foobar = $_product->get_attribute( 'myCustomAttribute' );
    $foobar == true ? $foo = "true" : $foo = "false";
    ?>

    // Add table row with custom attribute as a data attribute
    <tr data-foo=<?php echo "$foo"; ?>>...Content in here</tr>
  <?php 
  }
```

I know this is bad practise as it'll be overwritten when the plugin is updated.

I'm trying to add the same functionality into my template's functions.php file but after looking through the WooCommerce support docs I can't see anything that would help.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can copy the template file to your theme folder. So you'd have `wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php` - and you *don't* need to copy all templates - just the ones you want to modify/customize.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ! I didn't know that! Would upvote if I could!

Comment: You're welcome! And for further details, check out [this article](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/). :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to override the file, not edit it directly.

**How to Edit Files**

Edit files in an upgrade-safe way using overrides. Copy the template into a directory within your theme named /woocommerce keeping the same file structure but removing the /templates/ subdirectory.

**Example:** 
To override the cart.php file...

**copy:**
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php

**to** wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php

The copied file will now override the WooCommerce default template file.  Make your updates in the new file.

Here is [more detailed information](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).